# JS Regexp limit

Tags: javascript, regex

Very simple thing, but can't find it anyways..
How can i limit a regexp result?

Example string:

```
io=G4-WfdxQHfBLrcB7AAAC; connect.sid=s%3AKdRP6Bh_bFsN_9Br4TfTykVSqenUgpDA.ighSSEVvoIInT%2Fc7z%2B2HaQQRzwS6p7gkEqJs2ZQbw1k; sid=s%3ACte80repoZLXoDfMqABqrNcg9qdO0a5L.1I%2BFc61dYeyqNhmjxCVMiZEPgLvgolvMIohLAx22WYo
```

My current regexp:

```
/\ssid=(.*)/
```

Current result is:

```
sid=s%3ACte80repoZLXoDfMqABqrNcg9qdO0a5L.1I%2BFc61dYeyqNhmjxCVMiZEPgLvgolvMIohLAx22WYo
```

Desired result is:

```
s%3ACte80repoZLXoDfMqABqrNcg9qdO0a5L.1I%2BFc61dYeyqNhmjxCVMiZEPgLvgolvMIohLAx22WYo
```

How can i improve that?

Comment: The capture group gets everything after the `=`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Right, didn't know how to get it, like described below. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the first capture group as

```
match = str.match(/\ssid=(.*)/);
// match[0] will contain match after the `=`
```

Or more simply you can write

```
match = str.match(/\ssid=(.*)/)[1];
```

**Example**

```
str = "io=G4-WfdxQHfBLrcB7AAAC; connect.sid=s%3AKdRP6Bh_bFsN_9Br4TfTykVSqenUgpDA.ighSSEVvoIInT%2Fc7z%2B2HaQQRzwS6p7gkEqJs2ZQbw1k; sid=s%3ACte80repoZLXoDfMqABqrNcg9qdO0a5L.1I%2BFc61dYeyqNhmjxCVMiZEPgLvgolvMIohLAx22WYo"  
match = str.match(/\ssid=(.*)/)[1];
// Output
// => s%3ACte80repoZLXoDfMqABqrNcg9qdO0a5L.1I%2BFc61dYeyqNhmjxCVMiZEPgLvgolvMIohLAx22WYo
```

From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

> (x)
>
> Matches x and remembers the match. These are called capturing
>   parentheses.
>
> For example, /(foo)/ matches and remembers "foo" in "foo bar". The
>   matched substring can be recalled from the resulting array's elements
>   [1], ..., [n] or from the predefined RegExp object's properties $1,
>   ..., $9.
>
> Capturing groups have a performance penalty. If you don't need the
>   matched substring to be recalled, prefer non-capturing parentheses
>   (see below).

Comment: Thanks a lot, works. So it's because of paratheses? I make group, and than take it, right?

Comment: @Lazyexpert You got it !!. Every thing that is matched by the pattern in `(..)`  is caputured in groups numberd from 1 onwards. That is nth `()` forms the nth capture group which can be accessed using `match[n]`